# Why is my page blank?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've created a Web Part page in SharePoint designer and added some web parts (a Data View and a Text Filter), but when I preview it or browse to it on the site, the page is blank with no web parts on.

When I edit it in the browser, it's as if no web parts have been added.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Paste of Code - http://pastebin.com/ZMpeaipJ

Comment: You added WebPart or WebPart Zone?

Comment: @AakashMorya WebPart, the WebPart Zone was already there

Comment: Try by removing the filter webpart.

Comment: @HarryB that's not changed anything unfortunately

Comment: Can you see those webparts in the page maintenance mode?

Comment: @AmalHashim yeah, it shows Web Part Page Title Bar and E-GRC (XsltListViewWebPart)

Answer (score 1):

the webparts under the div with class ms-hide which nver shows up, remove the class ms-hide. check th line no 36 in the provided code

Comment: And below you can find a Style="display:none;" on the webpartzone called loc:TitleBar

Comment: I can't seem to edit that div in SP Designer, the background to the text is yellow and I can't seem to type or delete anything in those areas

Comment: Yellow text? Sounds like "advanced mode" is needed!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had actually inserted the code into the wrong part. There are two Zone Templates (one is further down) and I should've inserted the parts in there instead.